# MySQL One-to-Many to JSON format

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, json, left-join

I have two MySQL tables:

```
User (id, name)
Sale (id, user, item)
```

Where `Sale(user)` is a foreign key to `User(id)`, so this is a one-to-many relationship (one user can make many sales).

I'm trying to get this from the database and return it in JSON format for multiple users, so it would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "User 1",
    "sales": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "item": "t-shirt"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "item": "jeans"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "User 2",
    "sales": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "item": "sweatpants"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "item": "gloves"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Where the "sales" entities are nested within the entity of their corresponding "user".

So the question is, what is the best way to query this from the DB and turn it into JSON? I could run a query for all Users, then iterate through each one and run a query to get their sales, but this is quite slow. Or, I could do an outer join between Users and Sales and then parse that in code into the JSON format, but this sends excess information from the DB (includes the entire set of User data for each Sale) and requires looping through it all in code. Is there a convenient way to do this? I'm using Python 3.7, by the way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a SQL query that might meet your requirement.It uses [MySQL JSON_ARRAYAGG() aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) to generate an array of JSON objects (which are created using [`JSON_OBJECT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object)).

An intermediate level of grouping is performed within the join, to generate the `sales` JSON array of each user. Then the results are aggregated into a single line, with one column that contains the resulting JSON array of objects.

```
SELECT
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', u.id, 'name', u.name, 'sales', s.sales))
FROM
    user u
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            user, 
            JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', id, 'item', item)) sales 
        FROM sale 
        GROUP BY user
    ) s ON s.user = u.id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a091f9a27fe4cc908ab7f1954ae82d9)**

If you wrap the return value with `JSON_PRETTY`, the output is as follows :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "User 1",
    "sales": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "item": "t-shirt"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "item": "jeans"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "User 2",
    "sales": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "item": "sweatpants"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "item": "gloves"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

**Edit** : here is an (ugly) solution for MySQL < 5.7, where JSON support is not available. It relies only on string manipulation functions. Please note that this will only work as long as the varchar fields do not contain the `"` character :

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        '[', 
        GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( '{ "id":', u.id, ', "name":"', u.name, '", "sales":', s.sales, ' }' )  SEPARATOR ', ' ),
        ']'
    )
FROM 
    user u
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            user, 
            CONCAT( 
               '[', 
                GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( '{ "id":', id, ', "item":"', item, '" }' ) SEPARATOR ', '),
                ']'
            ) sales 
    FROM sale
    GROUP BY user ) s ON s.user = u.id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eqSwXxhdvaKyW5VyrdpKii/0)**

Comment: This is fantastic. Is there a way to have it automatically populate the JSON_OBJECT fields with the table fields, so I don't need to update the query if I add a field to the User table, for example?

Comment: ah nuts, I just realized that JSON_ARRAYAGG doesn't exist until MySQL 5.7. I'm stuck on 5.6 since I'm using AWS Aurora Serverless. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Jordan : it looks like [Aurora now supports MySQL 5.7](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/database/using-json-with-mysql-5-7-compatible-amazon-aurora/)...

Comment: Achieving what you want in MySQL 5.6 will be more complicated since there is no JSON support in this version... We would have to do it using pure string concatenation and aggregation...

Comment: @Jordan : updated my answer with a solution with string concatenation /aggregation functions only.

Comment: Aurora (instanced) does, but Aurora (serverless) does not support 5.7

Comment: @Jordan : please check my second query, that works for your use case ? I tested it on MySQL 5.6

Comment: Thanks for the updated query, unfortunately I can make no guarantees about there not being any quote characters in the fields so I think I will have to go with a much less efficient approach (unless you have any other ideas).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to join another table as JSON using a mix of the solutions here:

```
SELECT 
    PT.id, 
    PT.name, 
    (
        SELECT CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('id', CT.id, 'created_at', CT.created_at)), ']') 
        FROM CHILD_TABLE CT 
        WHERE CT.parent_id = PT.id
    ) AS childs 
FROM PARENT_TABLE PT;
```

Returns:

```
[
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "John",
        "child": "[
            {\"id\": 432, \"created_at\": \"2023-02-02\"},
            {\"id\": 543, \"created_at\": \"2023-02-02\"}
        ]"
    },
    {
        "id": 234,
        "name": "Mary",
        "child": "[
            {\"id\": 654, \"created_at\": \"2023-02-02\"}
        ]"
    }   
]
```